# Configure ReSharper's "Possible multiple enumeration" for other types

Tags: c#, resharper

ReSharper has the warning "Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable". Is it somehow possible to make ReSharper produce this warning for other types? Specifically, I want ReSharper to produce this warning for one of my own types.

Comment: Does your type inherit IEnumerable?

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey: Yes, it does. How does this help me?

Comment: I was ruling out the possibility that you were not inheriting the IEnumerable interface, which is what re-sharper is looking for in this case.

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey: Problem is: ReSharper shows it only fir this type and not for derived types.

Comment: Here's a feature request for this: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-325890

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ReSharper analysis is hard-coded to check for IEnumerable only